# Is there good way to create a android app without android studio?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I have a idea to make a app to find location of a bus in the bus stand.I need to what is the best way to create my app for android ?i don't have a good knowledge in android. i tried to create my app using ionic,angular and cordova but i couldn't emulate my app.Is there another way t create my app.please help.

Comment: use a mobile device rather then emulator. Or download penny motion.

Comment: You can write the code in notepad and then use gradle to compile, but I don't really see the point of using sub-optimal tools for the task. Android Studio is specifically designed for Android development, why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Pointless question to be honest. Either way you are going to have to code the app, the IDE you use is a subjective choice, although Android Studio is probably your best choice for Android. If you dont have good knowledge you are going to have to learn, there is no way to make an app without having to learn to code. Hybrids are possible but again (IMHO) a poor choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can develop Android Apps in many ways through coding using Android Studio,Eclipse,PhoneGap,Xamarin etc..
2. There is another method to develop an app without coding by which you can develop an app faster and easier.Some of the tools are as follow:

   1.[Configure.IT](http://www.configure.it)

   2.Appery.io

   3.[App machine](http://www.appmachine.com)

   4.Mobile Roadie

   5.TheAppBuilde

   6.Business Apps

   7.Good Barber

   8.App Inventer (using this you can create android app without code. )

Answer (score 1):

You can use eclipse bundled with adt tools to develop android projects for Android studio. Genymotion is very good for emulating your application.

Comment: You can give upvotes if the answer was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are a web developer then learning native android is quite difficult and time taking.
Using native emaluator is quite slow and sometime it doesn't start.

You can use genymotion to emaluate your app

Answer (score 0):

[Titanium Studio](http://www.appcelerator.com) is best for developers who wants to do mobile apps.  with this tool you can develop ios, android, windows, and blackberry too.

Its was opensource earlier but not now. you can develop the freely but when you upload to server you have to purchase an account.  see this example

```
var view = Titanium.UI.createView({
   borderRadius:10,
   backgroundColor:'red',
   width:50,
   height:50
});
window.add(view);
```

this will create a red view in ios and android .